# Redirect to admin login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

I am trying to make to login pages the first page for admin login and the second page for normal user.
I am checking if the login user is an admin or normal user by field in the database table type if the type = 1 that a normal user and if the type = 2 that is admin.
Now I am when I go to normal user login page and submit the login form the system redirect me to admin login page

Admin login route
/admin/login
Normal user route 
/users/login

Admin controller

```
<?php

class Admin extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        if($this->session->userdata('admin_login')) {
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
    }
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('admin/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
    }
    public function login() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $data['title'] = "Login";
            $this->load->view('admin/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
            $this->load->view('admin/footer');
        }
        else {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

            $user_id = $this->admin_model->login($email, $password);

            if($user_id) {
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_data' => $user_id,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'admin_login' => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success');
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is Invalid');
                redirect('admin/login');
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Users Controller

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if($this->session->userdata('user_login')) {
            redirect('operations');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = "Users";
        $this->load->view('users/header');
        $this->load->view('users/login');
        $this->load->view('users/footer');
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $data['title'] = "Login";
            $this->load->view('users/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('users/login');
            $this->load->view('users/footer');
        }
        else {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

            $user_id = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);

            if($user_id) {
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_data' => $user_id,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'user_login' => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success');
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is Invalid');
                redirect('operations');
            }else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is Invalid');
                redirect('users/login');
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Also I check if the user loggedin or not by this way

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_login')) {
      redirect('users/login');
}
```

Also I check if the admin loggedin or not by this way

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('admin_login')) {
      redirect('admin/login');
}
```

Opretions Controller code

```
<?php

class Operations extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->database();
         $this->load->model('stores_model');

         if(!$this->session->userdata('user_login')) {
            redirect('users/login');
         }
     }
     public function index() {
         $data['Dstores'] = $this->stores_model->get_d();
         $data['Lstores'] = $this->stores_model->get_l();
         $data['DLstores'] = $this->stores_model->get_dl();
         $this->load->view('operations/templates/header');
         $this->load->view('operations/index', $data);
         $this->load->view('operations/templates/footer');
     }

     public function add() {
        $data['title'] = "Add Store";

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('loading_date', 'Loading Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cargo_discharg_date', 'Cargo Discharge Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('container_number', 'Container Number', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('container_truck_number', 'Container Truck Number', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cargo_truck_number', 'Cargo Truck Number', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('operations/templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('operations/add', $data);
            $this->load->view('operations/templates/footer');
        }
        else {
            $this->stores_model->create_store();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Store was added successfuly');
            redirect('admin/stores');
        }
     }

     public function delete($id) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('stores', array('id =' => $id, 'user' => $this->session->userdata('email')));
        if($query->num_rows() === 1) {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('stores');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Store was deleted Successfuly');
        }
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'No Store with same ID');
        }
        redirect('operations');
    }

    public function edit($id) {
        $data['store'] = $this->stores_model->get_store($id);
        $this->load->view('operations/templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('operations/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('operations/templates/footer');
    }

    public function update() {
        $this->stores_model->update_store();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Operation Updated Successfuly');
        redirect('operations');
    }
}
```

What ca I do please help

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: problem is when

Comment: I trying to login as normal user the system redirect me to the admin login

Comment: You can try http://testoman.website/users/login

Comment: Your `Users/Login` controller redirects to `operations`, can you show the code for the `Operations` controller?

Comment: 1 mint I will add the code now

Comment: It work when I login as admin app functions work perfectly

Comment: I can't actually know what's wrong, but just try debugging your code using `var_dump()` until you find what's wrong

Comment: In the index() function of both the admin and user controller echo the type of controller it is e.g. index() { echo 'admin login'; } then go to the user login where you said the problem was and see if it says admin to determine if it is an issue with your routes. also make sure that in the form you are submitting to the correct controller e.g. for admin `/admin/login` .etc. basically just try and find out where your form is submitting to and insert print_rs for the session/other vars where necessary to determine what is going on.